# Как подавить вывод "Не определено" в lsfusion?

Tags: lsfusion

Сабж, собственно. Нужно чтобы в табличных частях не выводилась эта надпись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение не определено выводится для всех **строковых** типов, чтобы можно было отличить пустую строку от NULL (это важно во многих случаях, так как вся логика условий в lsFusion сводится к сравнению с NULL).

Насколько я знаю, в текущей (3-й) версии платформы это никак не настраивается. В качестве workaround можно при создании свойств оборачивать все в OVERRIDE с пустой строкой:

```
 f(a) = OVERRIDE g(a) + ' ' + h(a), '';
```

Но это все же не очень удобно. Возможно в будущих версиях возможность настраивать строку отображаемую при NULL появится, но пока непонятно насколько эта возможность критична.

Comment: Пользователям не нравится. Особенно тем кто интерфейсам 1С привык. Можно вместо пустых данных печатать -- или n/a. И короче и не так шокирует :)

Comment: Для этого она сделана достаточно блеклой. Но да, возможно для некоторых будет непривычно. Поэтому: https://github.com/lsfusion/platform/issues/345